# How I can Retrieve Facebook Albums using Graph API.?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Hello Guys I am working WPF app and I want to retrive all the Facebook photos into the albums so how I can retrieve this.

I dont want to use any powershell.

Thank you.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facebook graph api defines different objects with which you can interact, granted the right permission and access token.
The Album object is described here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/.

You haven't stated from where you want to retrieve the albums, a user? maybe a page?
As they wrote in that page:

> The User, Page and Application objects have an albums connection of
>   type album.

Once you get the albums connections from your object (let's say user), you can iterate over that collection, and then query for the album data (using http requests) and then iterate over the photos connections to get the actual picture in the album.